# Jquery - text box numbering preference

Tags: jquery

I've a page with 20 or so text boxes on it. Using Jquery is there a way to allow a user to type a number between 1 and 5 into each of the boxes and either stopping them from retyping the same one again or alternatively changing their selection if they do.

So for example I type 3 in the first box, 1 in the tenth box and 5 in the fourteenth box. I then type 1 in the second box, so Jquery (or whatever) resets the tenth box to zero and allows me to continue typing.

I also try and type 6 into the ninth box but I'm not allowed as the range is 1-5 only.

Perhaps there's a better way to accommodate this functionality, I'm open to suggestions. The basic functionality I'm trying to achieve is to allow a user express a preference for the items listed 1-20. They can only choose 5 items though and need to rate them 1-5 in order of importance.

I've considered dropdowns but the problem would be similar.

Comment: There is a way. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I was thinking of checking an array of values onblur or onfocus and seeing if the values are in there, resetting accordingly. Thing is, I was also thinking that maybe there was some jquery code written to accommodate this exact scenario which would save me time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a better way to deal with this kind of UI is to allow the user to sort them without typing. Sorting by dragging feels much more natural and doesn't require interruptions like moving your hand from the mouse to the keyboard several times. Here's an example fiddle using jQuery UI's sortable feature. I've put a class on the top 5 items to highlight those items that have made it into the top 5.

Bear in mind :nth-child doesn't work < IE9 so you'd need an alternative way of setting the style in older browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/bxprs/1/

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 3</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 4</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 5</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 6</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 7</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 8</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 9</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>Item 10</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: grey;
    color:white
}
li:nth-child(-n+5) {
    background: green;   
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

Comment: Hmm...I do like the look of this, I'll do some investigation and see if it's suitable. Thanks.

Comment: Marked as answer, I used it with some tweaking to accommodate postbacks in .net. THanks!